# Referencing dictionary values

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Global variable `group_vars/all.yml`

```
---
dir:
  website_A: /var/www/html/a
  website_B: /var/www/html/b
```

I have created Ansible role `health-check` which accepts input variable `site`, it can have values `website_A` or `website_B`. This role will perform some actions based on the input variable `site`. I tried with the following settings, but it didn't worked.

`chdir: "{{ "dir." + site }}"`

As per the [FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/faq.html), we can make this work using hostvars or vars dictionary, but I didn't succeed in that.

Answer (score 1):

You have a kind of unbalanced quotes.

Try `chdir: "{{ 'dir.' + site }}"` or `chdir: dir.{{ site }}`

Comment: both cases failed with the same error:

 `File \"/tmp/ansible_qRiFL5/ansible_module_command.py\", line 163, in main\r\n    os.chdir(chdir)\r\nOSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/dir.website_A'\r\n",`

it is trying to access invalid path '/root/dir.website_A' instead of '/var/www/html/a'

Comment: Thanks @Konstantin Suvorov for your prompt response.

This did the trick:

`chdir: "{{ dir[site] }}"`

Comment: Oh, man... _variable concatenation_ is quite misleading term in this case.